# printf works differently for unicode and multibyte

Tags: c++, windows, unicode, multibyte

I have a service which writes in a named pipe, it writes a DWORD, Its is then read by another process(both running in unicode)

When I try to receive the DWORD and convert it to a displayable string (TCHAR,char,wchar_t etc) and print it using printf in command prompt, I get uneven results with newline

```
HANDLE hOutput = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
TCHAR szBuffer[SIZEOF_BUFFER];
DWORD dwRead;

for (;;)
{
    if (!ReadFile(hRemoteOutPipe, szBuffer, SIZEOF_BUFFER, &dwRead, NULL) ||
        dwRead == 0)
    {
        DWORD dwErr = GetLastError();
        if (dwErr == ERROR_NO_DATA)
            break;
    }

    
    szBuffer[dwRead / sizeof(TCHAR)] = _T('\0');

    // Send it to our stdout
    printf("%s",szBuffer);
    fflush(stdout);
}

CloseHandle(hRemoteOutPipe);

hRemoteOutPipe = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;


::ExitThread(0);
```

the printf works fine for multibyte, but doesnt work fine for unicode, Kindly help me out

Comment: What do you mean "for unicode"? Unicode is usually just a database. But there are many way to encode unicode characters. In any case `printf` just send bytes (literally) to the terminal/console. It is the terminal/console job to interpret the bytes and to display them. Search for such terminal problems here

Comment: basically I have a exe, when i receive the data and print them, I see missing escape literals, when i compile my exe using unicode, \r \n literals are being missed out when printf is used. But the same code works fine for multibyte compiled exe file

Comment: If with *"running in Unicode"* you refer to the Windows compiler flag _UNICODE, it likely implies that you are sending UTF-16 encoding strings (which are *wide character* strings, not *multibyte character* strings). If so, `printf()` is likely a problem as it does not support wide characters string (UNICODE strings in the misleading Windows slang). And your terminal/console might also be a problem. As a first step, try to replace `printf()` with `wprintf()`.

Comment: You really should write a *simple* `main` program, i.e. a console program.  Work out the issue with `printf` with that simple program.  Once that's worked out, then apply those fixes to the larger program.  The program being a service or not, or whether you are reading from a file has little, to any bearing on the issue with `printf`.

Comment: @AnandhaMurthyB Are you sending the DWORD over the pipe as a binary value (which you should be) or as a string (which the code suggests you are)?

Comment: @Codo UTF-16 is **not** a wide encoding; it's variable-width just like UTF-8, but with 16-bit code units instead of 8-bit. But true, `printf()` is not equipped to handle that.

Comment: Its a open source software which I wanted to modify to a unicode compiled exe, https://github.com/kavika13/RemCom kindly refer the source code

Answer (score 0):

First off: `TCHAR` was an idea that made sense in 1995, not so in 2022. You get these weird errors. Secondly, you're tagging as C++, but you're not using `std::cout`. That is really the root cause of the problem: `printf` doesn't understand `TCHAR`, you'd need to use `_tprintf`.

Answer (score 0):

`TCHAR` is a preprocessor macro that maps to either `wchar_t` or `char` depending on whether `UNICODE` is defined or not, respectively.

The `%s` placeholder expects a `char*` string in `printf()`, whereas it expects a `wchar_t*` string in `wprintf()`.

Since you are using `TCHAR` strings, the output will not be what you expect when `TCHAR` is `wchar_t`, as that would be a type-mismatch in `printf()`. You would need to use `_tprintf()` in `<tchar.h>` instead, which is a preprocessor macro that maps to either `wprintf()` or `printf()` depending on `UNICODE`.